# QMessagebox not been declared in Qt error

Tags: c++, qt

In my assignment I keep getting the following error

```
C:\Users\bekkie\Documents\UNISA\2016\1sem\COS 2614 - OT PROGRAMMING\Assignments\Ass1Q1\main.cpp:32: error: 'QMessagebox' has not been declared
```

Line:

```
 sb = QMessagebox::question( 0,QString ("Sentence Feedback"), responce, `QMessageBox`::Yes | QMessageBox::No);
```

Please help! I would really appreciate it.

Here is all my details of my program:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2016-02-26T12:56:12
#
#-------------------------------------------------



     QT       += core gui

        greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

       TARGET = Ass1Q1
       TEMPLATE = app


       SOURCES += main.cpp\
        sentenceprocessor.cpp

    HEADERS  += sentenceprocessor.h

    FORMS    +=
```

---

```
#ifndef SENTENCEPROCESSOR_H
#define SENTENCEPROCESSOR_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
    class SentenceProcessor;
}

class SentenceProcessor : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    int getWordNumber(QString sentence);
    int getVowelNumber(QString sentence);
    bool isReversible(QString sentence);
    QString wordsReversed(QString sentence);
    QString formatSentence(QString sentence);

private:
    QString sentence;

};

#endif // SENTENCEPROCESSOR_H
```

---

```
    bool ok;
    QMessageBox::StandardButton sb;

    do
    {
        // Ask for sentence
        QString text = QInputDialog::getText(0, "Input Sentence", "Please insert Sentence:",QLineEdit::Normal, "", &ok);

        if (ok && !text.isEmpty()) {
            responce = "Your Sentence: " + text + "has " + nSentence.getWordNumber(list) +
                       "It also has " + nSentence.getVowelNumber(list) + "Vowels in it" + "Is your Sentence Reversible" +
                       nSentence.isReversible(text) + "Your reversed sentence reads: " + nSentence.wordsReversed(text);    
            sb = QMessagebox::question( 0,QString ("Sentence Feedback"), responce, QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No);
        }    
    }while (sb == QMessageBox::Yes);    

    return a.exec();
}
```

---

```
#include "sentenceprocessor.h"
#include <QStringList>
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QMessageBox>

int SentenceProcessor::getWordNumber(QString sentence)
{
    QString Words;
    QStringList list;
    list = sentence.split( " ");
    int WordNumber = list.count();

     return WordNumber;

}

int SentenceProcessor::getVowelNumber(QString sentence)
{
    int VowelNumber = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < sentence.length();i++)
    {
    if (sentence.contains("a")|| sentence.contains("e")||
            sentence.contains("i")||sentence.contains("o")||
            sentence.contains("u"))
        VowelNumber++;
}
    return VowelNumber;

}

bool SentenceProcessor::isReversible(QString sentence)
{
    bool reversible;
    QString OriginalString, reversedString;
    QStringList OriginalList = sentence.split(" ");
    QStringList reversedList = OriginalList;

    QStringList::iterator firstRecord = reversedList.begin();
    QStringList::iterator lastRecord = reversedList.end();
    {
    while (true)
        {
        if (firstRecord == lastRecord || firstRecord == --lastRecord){
           reversedString = reversedList.join(" ");
        }
        else{
         qSwap(*firstRecord, *lastRecord);
                ++firstRecord;
       }
    }
}
    if (OriginalList==reversedList)
        reversible = true;
    else
        reversible = false;

    return reversible;

}

QString SentenceProcessor::wordsReversed(QString sentence)
{
    {
        QString reversedString;
        QStringList reversedList = sentence.split(" ");


        QStringList::iterator firstRecord = reversedList.begin();
        QStringList::iterator lastRecord = reversedList.end();
        {
        while (true)
            if (firstRecord == lastRecord || firstRecord == --lastRecord){
             return  reversedString = reversedList.join(" ");
            }
            else{
             qSwap(*firstRecord, *lastRecord);
                    ++firstRecord;
           }
        }
    }

}

QString SentenceProcessor::formatSentence(QString sentence)
{
    QString FormatedString;
    FormatedString = sentence;

   int num = FormatedString.count();
    FormatedString.at(0).toUpper();


     FormatedString.at(0).toUpper();

     for (int i = 1; i < num; i++)
         FormatedString.toLower();

     if (FormatedString.lastIndexOf("."))
             return FormatedString;
             else
             return FormatedString = FormatedString + ".";
}
              ^
```

Comment: It is already included in the source file. The error is a mere typo.

Comment: @iksemyonov Yeah I noticed while editing the question.

Answer (score 4):

1. `#include <QMessageBox>` - *ok, this appears to be present, but you need one anyway, so let this stay here*.
2. `sb = QMessageBox::question(` not `sb = QMessagebox::question(`. C++ is sensitive to the case of identiers.

You may want to use an IDE with autocompletion and / or code analysis to catch errors like this one. The other option is to look at the code really closely when typing it in. (I prefer the latter method, since it very helpful when learning the language or a new library. See e.g. the practice of "whiteboard interviews" when they make you write code on paper or a whiteboard without using any tool or reference.)

Comment: Thank you very much. Cant believe I didn't see it. I corrected it. It finally gives my qinputdialog but it doesnt give my qmessagebox when I run it.

Comment: @CharleneBuys hard to tell without seeing your code but you might need to set the parent of the message box to `this` (it's `0` as of now) and the other thing that looks suspicious is that `exec()` is called after the message box-realted code, which might mean the latter has no effect.

Comment: @thuga look closer, there is a `do {` above - it's a `do {} while()` loop.

Comment: @iksemyonov My bad. The indentation threw me off.

Comment: @CharleneBuys You'd need to run the code in a debugger. Break at the line `(ok && !text.isEmpty())` and check the values of `ok` and `text`. Make it a habit to use the debugger, since debugging it's an integral part of the programming process. You need to get used to the idea of tracing and analyzing the *actual* behavior of your program and comparing it to the expected behavior.